# Command-line way of send pinging

Tags: command-line, ping

I have lots of Drupal powered website. Each of the website has [Multiping module](http://drupal.org/project/multiping) to pinging ping server.

Is there any way of send pinging through command-line?

I hope I can build dedicated server for pinging.

Comment: A "ping" in Drupal language is just a small http request with information about what node is being referenced and from where. You can replicate this action on the command line or in a script. I recommend `curl` to make the requests.

Comment: @Caleb: could have been an answer.

Comment: @Mat: It probably should be, but without actually putting together a request that passes the right parameters to make it the expected ping format I didn't feel like it actually answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

As Caleb notes, cURL is usually the weapon of choice for command-line
HTTP.  The tricky part - as Caleb again notes - is putting the request
together, especially for XML-RPC, where the server is likely looking
for a well-formed input.

But if you [poke around at the source for Multipin](http://drupalcode.org/project/multiping.git/blob/HEAD:/multiping.module#l96), you see that it's
not just a simple HTTP request (thought it does fall back to that) -
and it changes based on what services the target service has enabled
-- and, in the case of weblogUpdates -- special-cases what is sent:

```
// Ping! Check service method
if (!empty($pingservice->method)) {
  if ($pingservice->method == 'weblogUpdates.ping') {
    $result = xmlrpc($pingservice->url, $pingservice->method, $name, $base_url);
  }
  else {
    $result = xmlrpc($pingservice->url, $pingservice->method, $name, $base_url, $rss_url);
  }
}
else {
  $pingurl = strtr($pingservice->url, array(
    '%name' => urlencode($name),
    '%url' => urlencode($base_url .'/'),
    '%rss' => urlencode($rss_url),
  ));
  $result = drupal_http_request($pingurl);
```

And a few lines above, it's clever about deciding what rss URL to
send, based on taxonomy, etc.

So I'd suggestion one of two approaches.

1. If you just want to get something going, simulate the `drupal_http_request`
   by sending something like this:

   ```
   $ curl <target-pingservice-url> -d 'name=<your site name>' -d url=<your-url> -d rss=/rss.xml
   ```
2. Alternatively: if want all the behavior of MultiPing, you could
   extract that `_multiping_doping` function and run it from the
   command line directly by PHP.

   The workhorse function you'll need is Drupal's xmlrpc:
   http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/xmlrpc/7

Good luck!